# :dependent => :destroy does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I read lot of stuff about association (belongs_to, has_many ...) but I think I missed a point somewhere, and I can't find the right answer.

Here's my schema for posts:

```
create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
t.string   "titre"
t.text     "description"
t.string   "hastag"
t.string   "postimg"
t.integer  "utilisateur_id"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "posts", ["utilisateur_id"], name: "index_posts_on_utilisateur_id", using: :btree
```

When I create a new post, I send the "utilisateur_id" this way:

```
@post = Post.new(post_params)
current_user = session[:utilisateur_id]
@post.utilisateur_id = current_user
```

In the rails console, when I type

```
user = Utilisateur.find(id)
user.posts
```

and the rails console finds the posts associated with the user, does it mean that the association worked?

In my post model, I wrote `belongs_to :utilisateur, :dependent => :destroy` and in my utilisateur model, I wrote `has_many posts`.

When I destroy the user, the posts associated with it are not destroyed, and I don't understand why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
```

Comment: As backparkerhh says you want the dependent destroy on your User model.  The way you have it currently will delete the user if you delete a post they own.  Which will then leave the rest of the posts orphaned.

Comment: Oh well, i knew i missed a big point. Thanks a lot. I written the dependent destroy in the post model because in Mysql on delete => cascade is on the child, not the parent. Its working like a charm. Thanks again !

Comment: Its done, stackoverflow ask me to wait 5mn to accept it.